# Adding Named Objects in Blender with Python API

Tags: python, scripting, objects

**Motivation**: I would like to add multiple empties with sequential, but meaningful, names using the Python API with Blender.

**Issue**: I cannot name the objects as I add them.

**Question**: What can I add to the `bpy.ops.object.add()` code to give a name, or how can I change the name immediately after adding the object?

So far, to insert empties with (x,y,z) coordinates (1.1,1.1,1.1), (2.2,2.2,2.2), (3.3,3.3,3.3), and (4.4,4.4,4.4):

```
import bpy

x = (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)
y = (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)
z = (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)

for index,val in enumerate(x):
    bpy.ops.object.add(type='EMPTY', location=(x[index],y[index],z[index]))
```

They are added with sequential names:

1. Empty.001
2. Empty.002
3. Empty.003
4. Empty.004

Here is a screenshot of the output:
[Screenshot of Blender after running Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC2ge.png)

But, I want them to have names:

1. SpecifiedName.001
2. SpecifiedName.002
3. SpecifiedName.003
4. SpecifiedName.004

I cannot seem to just add the property name = "SpecifiedName" to read:

```
bpy.ops.object.add(type='EMPTY', location=(x[index],y[index],z[index])) ###DOES NOT WORK!!!###
```

If you are curious as to the final outcome I am looking to do, I want to plot several different datasets in x,y,z coordinates. Each empty from each dataset (and cooresponding name) will be linked to an mesh like a sphere or cube. This gives me the chance to animate a flythrough or rotation of 3D scatter plot data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use `bpy.ops.object.add()` the newly created object becomes the active object, so right after creating the object you can alter it's name with

```
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'new_name'
```

It is also possible to create objects without using operators. This approach will create the objects without altering the existing selection or active object.

```
import bpy

x = (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)
y = (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)
z = (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)

for index,val in enumerate(x): 
    new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('new_obj', None) 
    new_obj.location = (x[index],y[index],z[index])
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(new_obj)
```

Here 'new_obj' will be the name of the new object, if it is non-unique it will also get a numeric extension.

Comment: So the 'new_obj' will automatically create an empty without a location? 

What exactly is 'bpy.context.scene.objects.link(new_obj)' linking to?

 Is there a way to link or duplicate another object that I have created previously?

Comment: `new()` will create an object with a location of (0,0,0), you then set the location to place it where you want it. `link()` is adding the object to the scene - `bpy.context.scene` is the current scene. You can use `new_obj = object.copy()` to duplicate an existing object, then use `link()` to place it in the scene. Compare with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34692743/2684771)

Comment: OK. Thanks sambler. This all work. I would upvote your answer, but I do not have enough reputation at this point.