# Why isn't 'bpy.context.object.name' printing out the name of my newly created object?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a simple operator which creates an empty object and immediately prints out the object's name:

```
import bpy

class createEmpty(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Create an empty object"""
    bl_idname = 'make.empty'
    bl_label = 'Create an empty object'

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES')
        print(bpy.context.object.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class createEmptyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'create_empty_panel'
    bl_label = 'create empty object'
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = 'object'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('make.empty')

bpy.utils.register_class(createEmpty)
bpy.utils.register_class(createEmptyPanel)
```

When I run this from the console, it creates an empty object and prints its name, 'Empty'. However, when I click the button in the UI, it creates an empty object, but prints the name of the object that was selected, in my case 'Cube'.

Why is this? Is there a better way to select the object I just created, other than `bpy.context.object`?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45101/adding-named-objects-in-blender-with-python-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `active_object` instead:

```
def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES')
    print(bpy.context.active_object.name)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Blender doesn't switch the `bpy.context.object` until after the createEmpty operator has completed, hence the Cube's name was being printed. Your operator is invoked from the createEmptyPanel which has `bl_context = 'object'`, I suspect this has built in blocking of `bpy.context.object` changes.

Avoid this behaviour by using the lower level `bpy.data.objects.new` to make the empty. Change the execute function to avoid using `bpy.ops.object.empty_add()`, like:

```
import bpy

class createEmpty(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Create an empty object"""
    bl_idname = 'make.empty'
    bl_label = 'Create an empty object'

    def execute(self, context):
        # bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES')
        scene = context.scene
        objects = bpy.data.objects
        mt = objects.new("empty_name", None)
        mt.location = (0, 2, 1)
        mt.empty_draw_size = 2
        mt.empty_draw_type = 'PLAIN_AXES'
        scene.objects.link(mt)
        scene.update()
        print(mt.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class createEmptyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'create_empty_panel'
    bl_label = 'create empty object'
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = 'object'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('make.empty')

bpy.utils.register_class(createEmpty)
bpy.utils.register_class(createEmptyPanel)
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it does immediately give you a reference to the new empty.